KMM iOS Keyboard with languages that replace words
When I build my KMM app for iOS, I noticed the keyboard is not working as intended with languages like Chinese where on iOS you enter the string first then replace it with the characters while on Android they get entered in a different text field where the user needs to tap on the one they want.
Bug: bunch of texts gets added followed by the character replacement
Excepted: User types out their word, tap the character replacement, and all the ABCs are removed for their character
